# Add Bearer Keywork in Swagger SECURITY_DEFINITIONS

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, swagger

I am trying to use JWT in Django and swagger.

here is my swagger setting

```
'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'JWT': {
            'type': 'apiKey',
            'name': 'Authorization',
            'in': 'header',                  
        }
    },
```

Current URL format : `curl -X GET "http://localhost:8000/api/customer/" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization  eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiZXhwIjoxNjAzMTIyMzYyLCJqdGkiOiJkNzZhNWIwYTE1MmQ0ZWZlODZiN2E4ZTUzYWQ4NTA3YyIsInVzZXJfaWQiOjF9.8IdlDh"`

I would like to add `Bearer` keyword as prefix of `apikey`.How can I add that?

Comment: Does `django-rest-framework` support OpenAPI 3.0? OAS3 has a special security scheme for [Bearer auth](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/): `type: http` + `scheme: bearer`.

Comment: @Helen, Thanks but looks like 2.0.I use drf-yasg and its point to this doc https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#security-definitions-object

Comment: In this case consumers need to specify the `Bearer` prefix manually as part of the token value.

Answer (score 1):

You should used like this:

```
'SECURITY_DEFINITIONS': {
        'JWT': {
            'type': 'http',
            'scheme': 'Bearer'
            'in': 'header',                  
        }
    },
```

here is de doc:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/